# How to load a custom module with Dojo Require with a global scope?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Example

mainfile.js :

```
require(['someDojoModule', 'myModule.js'], function(SomeDojoModule){
    //Function does not exist
    myModuleFunction();

})
```

myModule.js :

```
require(['otherDojoModule'], function(OtherDojoModule){
    const msg = 'myModule';
    function myModuleFunction(){
        console.log(msg);
    }   
})
```

The above does not work, I know I can do it by setting myModule.js as declare and return an object, but I want it to be in a global scope to mainfile.js, how can I do that?

Or just a way that I can put `myModule.js` in a script tag in the header and have `myModuleFunction` be available globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you have to return an object. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)

**Module:**

```
define([otherDojoModule], function (otherDojoModule) {
return {
    msg: 'myModule',
    myModuleFunction: function () {
        console.log(this.msg);
    }
};
```

});

**Mainfile:**

*To make your function available globally*

```
require(["myModule"], function (myModule) {
        window.myModule = myModule;
    });
```

And you can use your function like `myModule.myModuleFunction();`

*Common case*

```
require(["myModule"], function (myModule) {
        myModule.myModuleFunction();
    });
```